How do I implement the mapbox-gl-geocoder plugin with mapbox-gl@3.5.1
Is the mapbox-gl-geocoder no longer maintained? I see very little activity here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder. Is there a newer replacement I just haven't found?
I'm migrating my project to mapbox-gl 3.5.1 but have hit a blocker.
"dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^5.0.2",
    "mapbox-gl": "^3.5.1",
    ...
}, 
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^5.0.0",  // I've tried building my project with this typing included as well as excluded
    ...
}

When @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder is included, I get many errors. Here's 2 examples:
Example 1:
Error: node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.d.ts:8293:2 - error TS2416: Property 'tileID' in type 'ImageSource' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ISource'.
Type 'CanonicalTileID | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CanonicalTileID | undefined'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanonicalTileID | undefined'.
8293  tileID: CanonicalTileID | null | undefined;
Example 2:
Error: node_modules/@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder/index.d.ts:270:40 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/.../app/node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl"' has no exported member 'FlyToOptions'.
270     setFlyTo(flyTo: boolean | mapboxgl.FlyToOptions | mapboxgl.FitBoundsOptions): this;
When @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder is excluded, I get many different errors. Here are examples:
Example 1:
Could not find a declaration file for module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'. 'c:/Users/.../app/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';ts(7016)
Example 2:
Error: src/app/services/map/layers/conditions.service.ts:238:133 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'GeoJSON'.
238     private _getClosestFeature(point: LngLat, features: (GeoJSON.Feature & { geometry: { coordinates: [ number, number ][] } })[]): GeoJSON.Feature & { geometry: { coordinates: [ number, number ][] } } {

I'm working with Angular vs17, i had same error and i solved with de nexts steps:

Verify you have installed @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder
Create types to mapbox module


Create a type declaration file in your project:
Create a file called mapbox-gl-geocoder.d.ts in the src directory or in a specific folder such as src/types.

Agrega el siguiente código al archivo mapbox-gl-geocoder.d.ts:
 declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder' {
 import { IControl, LngLatLike, Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

 interface GeocoderOptions {
    accessToken: string;
    mapboxgl?: any;
    placeholder?: string;
    zoom?: number;
    bbox?: [number, number, number, number];
    types?: string;
    minLength?: number;
    limit?: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}

export default class MapboxGeocoder implements IControl {
constructor(options: GeocoderOptions);

addTo(map: Map): this;
onAdd(map: Map): HTMLElement;
onRemove(map: Map): void;
setPlaceholder(placeholder: string): void;
setFlyTo(enable: boolean): void;
setZoom(zoom: number): void;
setProximity(proximity: LngLatLike): void;
setRenderFunction(fn: (feature: any) => string): void;
getProximity(): LngLatLike | undefined;
getZoom(): number | undefined;
query(params: any): void;

// Agregar el método `on` y otros métodos para los eventos
on(type: string, listener: (event: any) => void): this;
off(type: string, listener: (event: any) => void): this;
getResult(): any;
clear(): this;
}
}




Check TypeScript Configuration
Make sure your tsconfig.json file is configured correctly to include custom type declaration files:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"], // Incluye el directorio de tipos personalizados si lo creaste
    "types": ["mapbox-gl"]
  }
}


Import @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder into your Component.
Make sure you are importing the module as follows after performing the steps above:
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';



